# Search for used Range.NumberFormats in Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

On an overly abused workbook we've hit the limit and `NumberFormat`s can no longer be added. If we do want to add more we need to consolidate current formats. My code requires a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` as it uses the `Dictionary` class. Is there anything I can do to further improve performance?

I started by looking for a NumberFormat already known to be in use on a worksheet.

```vb
Private Function GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS(ByVal numberFormatToFind As String, ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = numberFormatToFind

    Dim searchArea As Range
    Set searchArea = ws.UsedRange
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Set firstCell = searchArea.Find(What:=vbNullString, After:=searchArea.Cells(searchArea.Rows.Count, searchArea.Columns.Count), SearchFormat:=True)
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = searchArea.Find(What:=vbNullString, After:=firstCell, SearchFormat:=True)

    If foundCell Is Nothing Or foundCell.Address = firstCell.Address Then
        Set GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS = firstCell
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS = Union(firstCell, foundCell)

    Do While foundCell.Address <> firstCell.Address And Not foundCell Is Nothing
        'Range.Find() is used as Range.FindNext() doesn't search for a SearchFormat.
        Set foundCell = searchArea.Find(What:=vbNullString, After:=foundCell, SearchFormat:=True)
        If foundCell Is Nothing Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS = Union(GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS, foundCell)
    Loop
End Function
```

The next step was to search for all the NumberFormats on a given worksheet. If the NumberFormat is non-General I care about it and store it. `delimitChar` is a module level variable `Private Const delimitChar As String = "|"` since it is also used later as part of the table creation.

```vb
Public Function GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorksheet(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorksheet = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = ws.Name

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
        If cell.NumberFormat <> "General" Then
            Dim formatWSKey As String
            formatWSKey = cell.NumberFormat & delimitChar & sheetName
            If Not GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorksheet.Exists(formatWSKey) Then
                Dim foundCells As Range
                Set foundCells = GetFoundNumberFormatOnWS(cell.NumberFormat, ws)
                GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorksheet.Add formatWSKey, foundCells.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

From there the next step was to get all the NumberFormats in a workbook.

```vb
Private Function GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorkbook(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim formatsInWorkbook As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set formatsInWorkbook = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Dim formatsInWorksheet As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set formatsInWorksheet = GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorksheet(ws)
        Dim keyValue As Variant
        For Each keyValue In formatsInWorksheet.Keys
            formatsInWorkbook.Add keyValue, formatsInWorksheet.Item(keyValue)
        Next
    Next

    Set GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorkbook = formatsInWorkbook
End Function
```

When one of the function returns I can then use it to create a table from the consolidated information. The `Keys` and `Items` are converted to Nx1 "vertical" array for population.

```vb
Private Function CreateTable(ByVal numberFormatsDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal addToWorkbook As Workbook) As ListObject
    Dim formatUsedOnWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set formatUsedOnWorksheet = addToWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    formatUsedOnWorksheet.Name = "UsedNumberFormats"
    formatUsedOnWorksheet.Range("A1").Value2 = "NumberFormat"
    formatUsedOnWorksheet.Range("B1").Value2 = "Worksheet"
    formatUsedOnWorksheet.Range("C1").Value2 = "Cells"
    Const dataStartRow As Long = 2
    With formatUsedOnWorksheet.Cells(dataStartRow, 1).Resize(numberFormatsDictionary.Count, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(numberFormatsDictionary.Keys)
        'FieldInfo preserves `0.000` and `0.0` as distinct formats. Otherwise they
        'are treated as `0` and their distinct format is not preserved.
        .TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=delimitChar, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat), Array(2, XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat))
    End With

    'Originally Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose() was used.
    'Under certain conditions it would error out
    Dim verticalArray() As Variant
    verticalArray = ConvertToVerticalArray(numberFormatsDictionary.Items)
    formatUsedOnWorksheet.Cells(dataStartRow, 3).Resize(numberFormatsDictionary.Count, 1).Value2 = verticalArray

    Set CreateTable = formatUsedOnWorksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, formatUsedOnWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
End Function

Private Function ConvertToVerticalArray(ByRef horizontalArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim lowerBound As Long
    lowerBound = LBound(horizontalArray)
    Dim upperBound As Long
    upperBound = UBound(horizontalArray)
    Dim elementCounter As Long
    Dim foo As Variant
    ReDim foo(lowerBound To upperBound, 0 To 0)
    For elementCounter = lowerBound To upperBound
        foo(elementCounter, 0) = horizontalArray(elementCounter)
    Next
    ConvertToVerticalArray = foo
End Function
```

The calling Sub takes the returned information and creates a table from it.

```vb
Public Sub AddWorksheetThatListsWhereNumberFormatsAreUsedInWorkbook()
    Dim usedInWB As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set usedInWB = GetAllNumberFormatsFromWorkbook(ThisWorkbook)
    With CreateTable(usedInWB, ThisWorkbook)
        .HeaderRowRange.Columns.AutoFit
        .Sort.SortFields.Add .ListColumns(1).Range
        .Sort.SortFields.Add .ListColumns(2).Range
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
End Sub
```